# Default html action called instead of jquery while clicking a form button

Tags: jquery, html, django

I have a form below with two buttons that I would like to use jquery to post to a url instead of the default form action.However, when I click on the Like Button or Dislike button, it still takes me to the saveFeedback url which is the default html form action, and not the jquery one. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
<body>

<form id="saveuserFeedback" class="form" action="{% url saveFeedback  %}" method="post" class="ajax">
...
...
<input type="submit" class="btn" id="Like" value="Like"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn" id="Discuss" value="Dislike"/> 
...
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#Like").click( function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            alert ('Like clicked');
            console.log('reached here');               
            $.post("/saveFeedback2/",{ feedbackStatus:"Like", feedbackNoteID : "12345" });                     
            });
         $("#Dislike").click( function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            alert ('Dislike clicked');
            console.log('reached here');               
            $.post("/saveFeedback2/",{ feedbackStatus:"Dislike", feedbackNoteID : "12345" });                     
            });
</script>
```

Comment: When you post with jQuery it doesn't do the redirect if that's what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, it now works. The problem was json formatting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write :

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

instead of

```
e.preventDefault();
```

And

write

```
$.post("/saveFeedback2/",{ feedbackStatus:"Like", feedbackNoteID : "12345" });
```

instead of

```
$.post("/saveFeedback2/",{ feedbackStatus:"Like", feedbackNoteID = "12345" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#saveuserFeedback").submit( ...
```

instead and it should works

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to be able to distinguish when Like is clicked or when Dislike is clicked. So how can I do that if I catch the #saveUserFeedback?

Comment: register click events on buttons and save which one was clicked

Answer (score 0):

Use both `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();`.

Also make sure you close the form `</form>`